# what happens to my google acct if I delete the gmail service?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I found a section in my Google acct where I can delete Gmail and Youtube services.

I want to keep my Youtube but thinking of deleting my Gmail acct since I'm not using it anymore.

I still want to use my Google acct since I have $100s worth of paid apps attached to it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. Your purchases are tied to the Google account ( if they weren't paid apps are not any more paid and can be used for free )

Google help [Delete your Google Account - Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en)

> What happens when you delete your account
>
> Once you delete your Google Account, you’ll no longer be able to use the following:
>
> - Services you have to sign in to, like Gmail, Drive, and Calendar.
> - Data associated with your account, including emails, photos, and records of transactions.
> - Subscriptions and content you purchased on **YouTube**, like movies and TV shows.
> - Content you bought on Google Play, **like apps**, movies, games, or music.
> - Information you saved in Chrome.
> - Your Gmail username. After you delete your username, it can't be used again by you or anyone else.

**Edit:** You can't use your you tube account either - is linked to Google account ( for tracking your playlists, purchases or rental, off line videos etc. If you log in to your Google account on web you can see your​ you tube activity , of course, if not disabled )

Comment: Can't keep YouTube without keeping Gmail?  Is that the way of it then?

Comment: No , you can't.  That's why highlighted that. As an example, let's say you rent or buy a movie on you tube. Payment is made through the means associated with your *Google account*. It's all tied up to thaw single account

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.  That was the way I understood it, but it would be nice if you could have an account that wasn't tied to one service (gmail) as a requisite.