# SignIn to Youtube (Android App) with Gmail but without adding Account

Tags: applications, gmail, youtube

I want to Sign-In to YouTube Mobile App on Android phone with Gmail Account but without adding the Account to Phones Account list , cause if I add the Account to phone then the account also shows up in the Gmail App which I don't want. I have a separate Gmail Account for Email and Sync and I have a separate account for YouTube which I don't want to be listed anywhere in phone except in YouTube App.

Is there a way to to Sign-In to YouTube App using Gmail account but not adding the whole account to Phone.

Comment: It's not possible AFAIK .Easier to remove the you tube related account from Gmail app

Comment: then everytime I have to use YouTube I will have to add it and then remove again once I am done, that sucks.Why so much tight coupling between phone accounts and App sign-in accounts?

Comment: "Why so much tight coupling between phone accounts and App sign-in accounts?" because the alternative would be that every app has to duplicate all of the sign-in functionality, and you'd have to go through the whole process from scratch with every app

Comment: @Dan Hulme that's what all the app do already (I configured an Gmail ID on Yahoo mail client), the rigidity only exists with YouTube app. What you say it only solves the general use case but users shouldn't be tied into the only option. The flexibility should still exist. If they want to signin with an account without adding it to phone accounts that option should work.

Answer (score 0):

- You tube is Google owned and therefore, is closely related to the purchases you make, your viewing habits which are monitored by Google (read ad and revenue generation). So, the tight coupling is inevitable as [answered here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175915/131553)
- That leaves you with the option of signing out of Gmail  (of the youtube related account) or  use alternative approaches like [FireFox addon](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154942/131553) or [IMAP approach](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/155191/131553) so that you have mail access as also youtube stand alone

It's a workaround